# NGINX always returns {"status":400,"message":"Bad request"} - not able to consume upstream api

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Below is my config:
am always getting bad request error when trying to consume api response. But it looks like the upstream api not getting recognized in the configs . please help.

api_gateway.conf

```
log_format api_main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                    '"$http_x_forwarded_for" "$api_name"';

include api_backends.conf;
#include api_keys.conf;

server {
    set $api_name -; # Start with an undefined API name, each API will update this value
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log api_main; # Each API may also log to a separate file

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <my-ip-address>; #have put my ip address where nginx installed

    # TLS config
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/test-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/test.key;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # API definitions, one per file
    include api_conf.d/*.conf;

    # Error responses
    error_page 404 = @400;         # Invalid paths are treated as bad requests
    proxy_intercept_errors on;     # Do not send backend errors to the client
    include api_json_errors.conf;  # API client friendly JSON error responses
    default_type application/json; # If no content-type then assume JSON
}
```

api_backends.conf

```
upstream warehouse_inventory {
    zone inventory_service 64k;
    server <ip>:443; #ip is where my upstream api hosted
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/api_gateway.conf; # All API gateway configuration
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; # Regular web traffic
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

/etc/nginx/api_conf.d/warehouse_api_simple.conf

```
# API definition
#
location /api/warehouse/inventory {
    set $upstream warehouse_inventory;
    rewrite ^ /_warehouse last;
}

# Policy section
#
location = /_warehouse {
    internal;
    set $api_name "Warehouse";

    # Policy configuration here (authentication, rate limiting, logging, more...)

    proxy_pass https://$upstream$request_uri;
}
```

curl https:///api/warehouse/inventory/try/health -k

```
{"status":400,"message":"Bad request"}
```

Log:
access.log

```
<ip-where-nginx-installed> - - [10/Feb/2020:06:19:29 -0600] "GET /api/warehouse/inventory/try/health HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.29.0" "-"
```

api-access.log

```
<ip-where-nginx-installed> - - [10/Feb/2020:07:04:20 -0600] "GET /api/warehouse/inventory/try/health HTTP/1.1"400 39 "-" "curl/7.29.0""-" "Warehouse"
```

Comment: Any solution to that? I have the same problem.